# Find $\arg(z)$, where $z = -\frac{\sqrt{7}(1+i)}{\sqrt{3}+i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This is my work so far:

I got the expression into the form $a+bi$ through some tedious algebra. I'll just list the final result here:

$-\frac{\sqrt{7}(\sqrt{3}+1)}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{7}(1-\sqrt{3})}{4}i$

When I solve for $|z|$ I get $\frac{\sqrt{14}}{2}$, which matches the answer in my textbook. However, when I solve for $arg(z)$ I get $\frac{11\pi}{12}$, while the book lists it as $\frac{13\pi}{12}$. I got my answer by solving for $cos (\theta) = \frac{a}{|z|}$, where $\theta = arg(z)$. Nothing seems wrong, so not sure if the answer in the book is a typo or I'm making a mistake.

Edit: I forgot a negative sign, I understand how the answer is derived now. Thanks!

Comment: And I get $\pi/12$. I didn't bother with the tedious algebra though.

Comment: `I got the expression into the form a+bi` That's not the best way to go about it in this case. Rather, note that $\,\arg(1+i)=\pi/4\,$ and $\,\arg(\sqrt{3}+i) = \ldots\,$

Comment: How'd you come to that answer without the algebra?

Answer (score 3):

$$Arg(z) = Arg(\sqrt{7}(1+i))-Arg(\sqrt{3}+i)=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{6}=\pi/12.$$

Comment: It seems the book has a typo then, I'm not sure where $\frac{13\pi}{12}$ comes from.

Comment: The minus sign means reflect about the origin, or rotate by $\pi$ radians.

Answer (score 0):

$$\textrm{Arg} (z) = \textrm{Arg}(-1)+ \textrm{Arg}{\sqrt{7}}+\textrm{Arg}(1+i)-\textrm{Arg}(\sqrt{3}+i) = \pi+ 0+\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{13\pi}{12}.$$